# How to display a whole php website file set in apache2?

Tags: server, apache2, php, xampp, github

I am new to web page design, I have seen graph editors used for example in windows. The question is that I have been working on Ubuntu server and I have done everything through vim and saving those files in a page that appears as index, only the files are shown.And I have a web page repository (with PHP files and directories) that I made in XAMPP. How can I make this whole set of files and directories display as a web page and not show only files and directories?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question by adding: Ubuntu Server version, if you installed PHP. I assume you already installed apache2 package. Also I believe you need to install package: libapache2-mod-php.

Answer (score 1):

You should have an index.php or an index.html in the directory to prevent showing the directory content in the first place and showing the content instead.

To disallow file listing in apache for all dirs check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing